# How to remove strange border from a listviewitem when mouse is over

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I have a `listview` with `listviewitems`. I set style triggers to override the default behavior of `IsMouseOver`

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

I am still left with a strange thick border at the top (see picture) that I can't seem to be able to remove no matter what I do. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Below is my entire xaml code for setting up the `listview`:

```
<ListView Height="177" Margin="52,12,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Padding="-1">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Bradley Hand ITC"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Header="Task ID" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Task Title" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Task Status">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Completed}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: it appears only when the mouse is over?

Comment: Yep, only on mouse over. Very strange. I was trying to add some more setters with margins and padding and whatnot  but nothing works.

Comment: which properties are you setting when declaring your ListViewItem?

Comment: Thanks @Cfun, please see my edited op that now includes the entire xaml code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Template out your ListViewItem template, then set its border thickness to 0:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#1F26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#A826A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3DDADADA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFDADADA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You'll also need to set this template in your ListViewItem style:

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemControlTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Strange my bindings are not working anymore and checkbox disappeared.

Comment: You must be overriding the ContentTemplate. Try replacing the ContentPresenter tag in the ControlTemplate with just `<ContentPresenter />`.

Comment: The same behavior: all columns items gone and replaced by namespace.mylist. where mylist is the list I have used in itemssource binding.

Comment: Same here, all bindings are gone..

Comment: Strange, columns and bindings all still work fine for me. Only other thing I can suggest is to generate the template yourself instead of using the one I've provided. Go to the control's properties, go to Miscellaneous -> Template, click on the little square to the right of it and select "Convert to new resource". If your bindings and columns etc are all in order then you can edit the border in that template instead.

Comment: in fact I already did and it was identical to your template.